# RadioButton has shadow in Firefox, but not in Google Chrome

Tags: html, radio-button, css

Here's what it looks like in Firefox:

[image]

What is looks like in Chrome:

[image]

Here are the CSS rules I'm using:

```
<div class="checkbox-field">
    <p>Mr.</p>
    <input type="radio" name="prefix" value="mr" />

    <p>Mrs.</p>
    <input type="radio" name="prefix" value="mrs" />
</div>

.checkbox-field input {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 46px;
    border: 1px solid #A97232;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -1px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -1px black;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -1px black;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    color: #636363;
    behavior: url(/Public/stylesheets/PIE.htc);
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

JSFiddle example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zFNRy/

Answer (score -1):

Please normalize your styles: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/